# Python: How to store mutable variables like sets?

Tags: python, variables, set

I wanted to store a set and afterwards remove some elements inplace like:

```
>>> A = set({1,2,3})
>>> B = A
>>> A.remove(3)
```

But so `B` changes also:

```
>>> B 
set([1, 2])
```

Is there a way to store `A` and not changing `B` without using:

```
>>> A = A - {3}
```

Comment: If you're expecting statements like `B = A` to make a copy, you should probably read up on [what Python variables are and what assignment actually does in Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for this hint, this is a very good summary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to write like this:

```
A = {1,2,3}
B = A.copy()
A.remove(3)
print(B)
```

Prints:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: You can also do `B = A.copy()`  This method exists on `set` and also provides a deepcopy without the import

Comment: In this case, `copy.deepcopy()` wouldn't be required, `copy.copy()` would suffice.

Comment: @sedavidw: `set.copy()` is a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: You're right in that it's a shallow copy, but here a shallow copy is actually okay, mistyped my comment

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `deepcopy` from `copy`.

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> A = set({1,2,3})
>>> B = deepcopy(A)
>>> A.remove(3)
>>> A
set([1, 2])
>>> B
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use copy, set is a collection of immutable object, element of set can't be changed in place, Hence deep copy is not needed.

```
a = set({1,2,3})
b = a.copy()
a.remove(1)
>>> a
set([2, 3])
>>> b
set([1, 2, 3])
```